# Comparison of growth of entire functions in a $p$-adic field

Tags: p-adic-analysis, p-adic

Let $p$ be a prime number, $\Omega_p$ be the spherically complete extension of $\mathbb C_p$. Consider two entire functions on $\Omega_p$: $f(z)=\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nz^n$ and $g(z)=\sum_{n\ge0}b_nz^n$. Assume that for all $n\in\mathbb N$, one has $|a_n|_p\le|b_n|_p$ and for an infinite set of indices $n$, $|a_n|_p<|b_n|_p$. Denote for $r\in\mathbb R^+$, $M_f(r)=\sup_{\substack{z\in\Omega_p\\|z|_p<r}}|f(z)|_p$ and $M_g(r)=\sup_{\substack{z\in\Omega_p\\|z|_p<r}}|g(z)|_p$. Can one assert that for all $r<1$, $M_f(r)<M_g(r)$? The large inequality is obvious.

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: I think not. You should be able to read off $M_g(r)$ from the Newton polygon of $g$, so if you remove coefficients that don't affect the Newton polygon to get $f$, you could have $M_f(r)=M_g(r)$ for all $r$. Have you tried to compare $g(X)=\sum_{n \geq 1} X^n/n$ and $f(X)= \sum_{k \geq 0} X^{p^k} / p^k$?

Comment: Oops, I didn't read 'entire' in your question. My example above is holomorphic on the open unit disk only.

Comment: Fix the Newton polygon of $f$ and for simplicity suppose the lengh of each edge $\geq 2$. Suppose that the Newton polygon of $g$  is the same and suppose that for indices $n$ not corresponding to vertex of the Newton polygon one has $\vert a_n\vert_p <\vert b_n\vert_p$. All your hypothesis are fulfilled,  but $f$ and $g$ having the same Newton polygon implies $M_f(r)=M_g(r)$.